# Simulate Enter key after typing URL

Tags: selenium, automation, appium

I need to know how to simulate the Enter key press after typing in a URL in a mobile web browser using sendKeys().I tried

```
    driver.sendKeys("http://www.google.com\n");
```

which did not work and

```
    driver.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

just clears the whole url box.

So it would be helpful to know.
BTW i am using Appium server for the automation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope this will help.

```
driver.sendKeys("http://www.google.com", webdriver.Keys.ENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it for you.  Enjoy!

```
WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector('the selector');

we.sendKeys("your text" + Keys.ENTER);
```

If you'd prefer to method chain the whole call

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector('the selector').sendKeys("your text" + Keys.ENTER);
```